# use php variable in json

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am trying to integrate a third party API (positionly.com) into a WordPress member site.
I am using the following code to add a positionly level to the corresponding membershipmouse member level

```
$base_url = POSITIONLY_API_URL;$url = $base_url . '/accounts.json'; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  $headers = array (
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Token: " . POSITIONLY_TOKEN
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$user_level = mm_member_data(array("name"=>"membershipId"));
    $plan = '');
    if($user_level = 2){
        $plan = "ClickMinded Bronze";
    } elseif ($user_level = 3){
        $plan = "ClickMinded Silver";
    }elseif($user_level = 4){
        $plan = "ClickMinded Gold";
    }
    // assign membermouse custom field a value
    $userdata['cf_1'] = $plan;

     //sets the positionly values to equal the membermouse values
    $post_params['owner_attributes[email]'] = $userdata['email'];
    $post_params['owner_attributes[name]'] = $userdata['first_name'] . ' '.$userdata['last_name'];
    $post_params['owner_attributes[password]'] = $user_password;
    $post_params['owner_attributes[plan_name]'] = $userdata['cf_1'];


    $post_string = http_build_query($post_params);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

// it breaks somewhere in here according to var_dump($result) the positionly plan always comes up as ClickMinded Silver
   $json = json_decode($result);
     if( $json->status == "ok" ){

    add_user_meta($userdata['member_id'], 'positionly_token', $json->token);
    add_user_meta($userdata['member_id'], 'positionly_id', $json->account->id);
    add_user_meta($userdata['member_id'], 'positionly_plan', $json->account->plan));
```

Have been in touch with the support at positionly and membermouse.

Have looked through several articles here and elsewhere "using php with json". Such as [Get value of JSON object in PHP variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915053/get-value-of-json-object-in-php-variable) [Using PHP Variables in Javascript with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261142/using-php-variables-in-javascript-with-json)

I have tried json_encoding the $plan variable I have gone through each step with var_dump and get the correct $plan -> level but it will not transfer to the json results.

I am at a loss. Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Where is your `curl_init` at which `url` you are doing `curl` ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here.  JSON is not a scripting language, so I don't know how you would "use php variable IN JSON".  What does `var_dump($result)` show? What does `var_dump($json)` show?

Comment: Mike yeah I worded that wrong. What I am trying to do is insert a positionly plan 'Gold, Silver, or Bornze' into a corresponding membership level created in WordPress using Membermouse. The trouble I am having is switching the positionly plan. They have a default plan silver, when I run var_dump($json) or var_dump($results) I get the default silver plan. not the plan the user selected

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing curl properly. You should provide the url to hit and also if you don't set the CURL_RETURNTRANSFER to true curl will not return the result instead it will just return true.

Change your code like :

```
$ch = curl_init('https://auth.positionly.com/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURL_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Raheel,  I just added the cURL init. I have inherited this project and assumed that part was done correctly. From the little documentation I have from positionly I was thinking it was in the JSON not switching but will try your suggestion

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURL_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` this line is must when you expect result from curl

Answer (score 0):

It was in the JSON had to add a new function, that used positionly's switch.json

```
function lina_update_user_plan($id, $plan){
$base_url = POSITIONLY_API_URL;

$url = $base_url . '/accounts/'.$id.'/switch.json';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$headers = array (
                  "Connection: keep-alive",
                  "Accept: application/json",
                  "Token: " . POSITIONLY_TOKEN
                  );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$post_params['plan'] = $plan;

$post_string = http_build_query($post_params);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);

if( $json->status == "ok" ){
    return true;
}
return false; }
```

Then we had to call the new function in the original function so if there was a status change it would add or update the user depending on the case

```
function lina_mm_member_add($userdata){
$base_url = 'https://api.positionly.com/v2/clickminded';
$base_url = POSITIONLY_API_URL;

$url = $base_url . '/accounts.json';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$headers = array (
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Token: " . POSITIONLY_TOKEN
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 $_REQUEST['mm_field_last_name']; 
 $user_password =    $_REQUEST['mm_field_password'];

    $plan = '';

    $user_level = $userdata['membership_level'];

    if($user_level == 2){
        $plan = "clickminded-bronze";
    } elseif ($user_level == 3){
        $plan = "clickminded-silver";
    }elseif($user_level == 4){
        $plan = "clickminded-gold";
    }

$post_params['owner_attributes[email]'] = $userdata['email'];
$post_params['owner_attributes[name]'] = $userdata['first_name'] . ' '. $userdata['last_name'];
$post_params['owner_attributes[password]'] = $user_password;
$post_params['owner_attributes[plan_name]'] = $plan;

$post_string = http_build_query($post_params);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);
   if( $json->status == "ok" ){
    add_user_meta($userdata['member_id'], 'positionly_token', $json->token);
    add_user_meta($userdata['member_id'], 'positionly_id', $json->account->id);

    //Update user's plan:
    $ret = lina_update_user_plan($json->account->id, $plan);

    if( $ret == true )
        add_user_meta($userdata['member_id'], 'positionly_plan', $plan);
    else
        add_user_meta($member_id, 'positionly_switch_plan_status', "Switch Failed");


}
```